# Tomcat 8.5.6 and Blob:// Origin headers

Tags: tomcat, blob, geoserver

We have a map based web application that requests map tiles from a WMS server (geoserver) running on Tomcat 8.5.6. We have CORS configured and it works for 99% of the requests, BUT, Internet Explorer sends an origin value of 'Blob://' for a particular request type (vector tiles that are binary) and i can't get tomcat to play well with these, it just returns a 403.

I've tried adding 'Blob://' to the allowed origins but still no result. Every other browser is fine of course, it's just IE11 that's causing problems.

Any advice?